# A word to describe an incident or event that may or may not have taken place

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word that can be used to describe an **incident** or **event** that may have taken place but people are not sure if that event actually took place because there is a lack of comprehensive evidence.

For example many people believe that the **[Roswell Incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roswell_UFO_incident)** is actually true, however others believe that such an incident did not take place.

Another example is an event from an Eastern religion called **[Mahabharat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahabharata)** that is considered to be true by many people, however others differ suggesting that there is no conclusive evidence to suggest that this event actually took place.

Comment: I guess this could be a **Schrödinger's event**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [***purported***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purported) - said to be true or real but not definitely true or real

If things are more certain, you can bump the status of a *purported event* up to *putative*:

> [***putative***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/putative) -  generally believed to be something

Answer (score 16):

Consider *[alleged](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=alleged)*

> Represented as existing or as being as described but not so proved; supposed: an alleged conspiracy; an alleged traitor; an alleged victim of a crime.

*American Heritage Dictionary*

Similarly *[claimed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/claim)*

> to say that something is ​true or is a ​fact, ​although you cannot ​prove it and other ​people might not ​believe it

*Cambridge Dictionaries Online*

Also

> - supposed
> - declared
> - assumed
> - so-called
> - apparent
> - rumoured
> - stated
> - described
> - asserted
> - presumed
> - affirmed
> - professed
> - reputed
> - hypothetical
> - averred

Comment: +1 for the "supposed" suggestion. I've heard that used many times.

Answer (score 1):

[Apocryphal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apocryphal) would be a good way to describe the alien landing at Roswell.

Comment: no no no!!!   Brummie, "apocryphal" simply means ***you do not know the author***.  It is quite incorrect, when folks use it to mean "may be legendary".

Comment: the word simply comes from "apocrypha" in jewish religious writing - it simply means nothing more than "margin note, by unknown writer".  the word just means "origin unknown" or "author unknown".

Comment: Joe, the origin is certainly from the Apocrypha but the word carries a meaning beyond text attribution.  Here is a quote from Fanny Hill: "Charles, already dispos'd by the evidence of his senses to think my pretences to virginity not entirely apocryphal, smothers me with kisses, begs me, in the name of love, to have a little patience, and that he will be as tender of hurting me as he would be of himself."

Comment: Hi Brumm - that author used it incorrectly, as do many people.  It's a bit like "decimate", you know what I mean?

Comment: Please don't quote such hot passages this early in the morning bud!  :)

Comment: The misuse of decimate does irritate me to a spectacular degree, I admit.  It's hard to decide at what point we accept a drift (or in this case, expansion) of the use of a word as a new meaning.  Wiktionary, for example, gives this as a third definition: "Of dubious veracity; of questionable accuracy or truthfulness; anecdotal or in the nature of an urban legend." whereas some sources do not cite it at all. Thankfully, it's afternoon here, so the adventures of Miss Hill seem a little more appropriate.